# Tensorflow2 Keras Tuning both units and activation function

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, activation-function, keras-tuner

I am trying to setup a Keras tuner to simultaneously tune both the number of layers and the activation function. The network attempts to warp a 2D function into another 2D function. I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function: sigmoidtanh
```

My code is below:

`python`

```
def euclidean_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
return tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=1)

def model_builder(hp):
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(2,)),

#===Tune number of layers===#
for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 2, 5)):
    #===Tune number of units and activation in each layer===#
    hp_units = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=12, max_value=512, step=10)
    activation = hp.Choice('activation_' + str(i), ['linear', 'relu', 'selu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh'])
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units, activation=activation))

#===Add Final Layer===#
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='linear'))

#===Compile===#
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=euclidean_distance_loss, metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

return model

b_tuner = BayesianOptimization( model_builder,
                            objective = 'val_mean_squared_error',
                            max_trials = 10,
                            executions_per_trial = 15,
                            directory = 'output',
                            project_name = 'b_tune_nn' )


b_tuner.search(x_train_points, y_train_points, epochs=25, validation_split=0.2)
```

Now if I write:

```
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units, activation='tanh'))
```

Everything works well. What am I doing wrong in specifying my model?

If you need more context, please let me know.

Comment: Your model's code did not produce the error for me on Colab.

Comment: @Frightera Should that make a difference? I am running python3.8 on an ubuntu linux machine.

Comment: I am not sure, but I posted a possible fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code which works for me:

```
import kerastuner as kt
import tensorflow as tf
from kerastuner import BayesianOptimization
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.randn(1000,20)
y_train = np.random.randn(1000,2)

def euclidean_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=1)

def model_builder(hp):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(2,)),

  #===Tune number of layers===#
  for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 2, 5)):
    #===Tune number of units and activation in each layer===#
    hp_units = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=12, max_value=512, step=10)
    activation = hp.Choice('activation_' + str(i), ['linear', 'relu', 'selu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh'])
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units, activation=activation))
  #===Add Final Layer===#
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='linear'))

  #===Compile===#
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=euclidean_distance_loss, metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

  return model


b_tuner = BayesianOptimization( model_builder,
                            objective = 'val_mean_squared_error',
                            max_trials = 10,
                            executions_per_trial = 15,
                            directory = 'output',
                            project_name = 'b_tune_nn' )


b_tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, validation_split=0.2)
```

Edit:

```
pip uninstall keras-tuner
pip install -U keras-tuner # get the latest version
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  I still get the same error...this didn't work :-/

Comment: Interestingly...even when I have instead '['linear', 'relu', 'selu']' (dropping sigmoid and tanh) I STILL get the same error. So perhaps something isn't installed correctly?

Comment: I just tried both of them on my local environment which uses python 3.8, there was no error. Something might be wrong with your installation. The code snippets were fine for me with some dummy data.

Comment: Okay...do you know how I could wipe the whole thing and start over?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It just installed keras-tuner 1.0.2 again...

Comment: You sure you don't have any *more* errors in the code somewhat related to code snippet you've posted? If so, I am not sure what triggers this error.

Comment: No, I suppose I am not sure. Could you post your dummy data code so I could check what does work?

Comment: I posted the complete code with the original form as your post.

Comment: Thanks alot! Unfortunately it still didn't work....

Comment: Well, I am sorry I don't have a clear idea why it happens.

Comment: Its okay -- I have another setup that I just ported everything to and it worked. Thanks for your help!!